# file is not being written in scala

Tags: file, scala

I have a file on which are stored some informations, eg.

```
0,0,0.0,0.00266920744152335,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,0.0,0.0,0.9385656429557993,1.0,0.0,0.0,0
1,0.0,0.0,0.9385656429557993,1.0,0.0,0.0,0
1,0.0,0.0,0.9385656429557993,1.0,0.0,0.0,0
0,0,0.0,0.00266920744152335,0.0,0.0,0.0
...
```

I create two more files on which i want to split the informations stored in `textLines`

```
val textLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data/sample/textFile.txt")
val first = new java.io.PrintWriter("data/sample/first.txt")
val second = new java.io.PrintWriter("data/sample/second.txt")
for (line <- textLines.getLines()) {
      val row = line.split(",")
      if (row(0).equals("0"))
        first.println(line)
     if (row(0).equals("1")) 
        second.println(line)
    }
    first.close()
    second.close()
    textLines.close()
```

the `first` file is written well, the `second` file remains blank.

what's wrong?

Comment: You should print the value of row in order to know if at one moment, row has the value "1" because I think ``row`` has never the value 1 so you will never entering in the second ``if`` condition.

Comment: i enter in the second if..

Comment: I just tested your code with the sample data you provided as I saw no errors and it is working on my computer. Can you check `second.txt` permissions/path? Have you tested it with the same input you provided?

Comment: It works for me. I tried it with the data you provided.

Comment: @mziccard i don't know why.. but clean project fix the problem.......

Comment: please answer yourself ans accept it to close the question

Comment: I think printWriter methods don't throw exceptions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html . May be there was a runaway lock was on the second file which the clean project removed. May be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but cleaning the project resolve this issue.